# Programmatically find valid values/data type that a Simulink block parameter accepts

Tags: matlab, simulink

In Simulink, I can get value of a block dialogue parameter that is already given using `get_param` function. However, I'm interested in finding possible valid values that a block dialogue parameter accepts. For example, The [`Sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sum.html) block accepts any combination of + and - signs only for its `Inputs` parameter. Is there a way to programmatically figure out this information?

To clarify, I want a function/method where I can pass as input a Simulink Block's name and a dialog parameter of that block. For example, I will pass `Sum` as a Simulink block name and `Inputs` as a parameter of that block.

What I expect as output is, `+` and `-` characters, so that I understand I can only use `+` and `-` characters for this block's `Inputs` parameter.

The page [Block-specific Parameters](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/block-specific-parameters.html) lists the valid (and default) values for different Simulink blocks' parameters in the `Values` column of each table. Is there a way to find this information programmatically i.e. passing a block type/handler in some function and getting the validation rules for a particular parameter of that block?

Thanks!

Comment: I'd be very surprised if you can do this in any generic way.  Many parameters can be specified as MATLAB variable names, so just getting the name from the dialog isn't going to tell you anything.  Even for the `sum` block the user can specify an integer, not just +'s and -'s.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that the Sum block's `Inputs` parameter accepts integers, till I checked the documentation page of the block. It looks like going through individual block's documentation is the best (or only?)  way, as not all information is available in this page "Block-specific Parameters" I linked in my question.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look [at the possibilities to check parameters in C MEX S-Functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/sfg/mdlcheckparameters.html) it is "free" implemented C code which checks the parameters. At least for such cases there is no way to get a set of accepted parameters. The only possibility is to test pragmatically if a special value is accepted:

```
value_to_test='++9'
old=get_param('s1/Add','Inputs')
try
set_param('s1/Add','Inputs',value_to_test);
accepted=true;
set_param('s1/Add','Inputs',old);
except
accepted=false;
end
```

Comment: Thanks. One problem with this approach is that the set of possible `value_to_test` is huge, and how do I minimize the set of possibly accepted characters for a parameter.

Comment: I know that this is not what you asked for, but it is the best possible solution. Having compiled c code which accepts / rejects your input, you practically have a black box.

Comment: Thanks again. Are *all* of the blocks in a model replaced by C (or some other) code before even running a simulation? I am not talking about code generation, just running a simulation using the Simulink software.

Comment: Many blocks are implemented in C, they are not replaced by C code. There exists no other implementation. But to my knowledge all parameters are checked by either C or MATLAB code.

Comment: Sorry I chose wrong term when saying "replaced". I wanted to ask this - when running a simulation is Simulink directly running (compiling - then executing in user machine) that block's code? Now as a whole for the model, is a piece of code generated using all of the blocks' code and that code (for the model now) is being run in user machine every time a simulation is run? Thanks.

Comment: I think this discussion is more related to your other question, did you read the link I put there?

Answer (score 0):

Beside the already suggested solution, you can check this out for a Gain block:

```
dlgParams = get_param(gcbh, 'DialogParameters');
dlgParams.Gain.Validity
%A struct with all accepted data, like: datatype, complexity, sign
dlgParams.Gain.Validity.Sign
%Returns: {'positive'  'negative'  'zero'}
```

This looks promising. However, a similar property is not available for Sum block. you can check the (dlgParams.Inputs) struct for ideas though.

*Writing as an answer since I can't comment yet.*